# How to set a relationship between two entities that don't have an (integer) foreign key?

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

In my database I have the two tables `tblOrders` and `tblPayments`, both containing a property named `ReferenceNumber (varchar 50)`. Unfortunately `tblPayments` doesn't have a foreign key pointing to `tblOrders`, so the only way to put the records from these two tables in relationship is by referring to the matching `ReferenceNumber` (1 order can have n payments).

In my ASP.NET Core 1.1 application that uses Entity Framework Core I'm trying to define this relationship for two models `Order.cs` and `Payment.cs`.

In the related configuration files I tried to set them up as following:

OrderConfiguration.cs:

```
    public void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(m => m.Id);

        builder.Property(m => m.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
        ... several other mappings...

        builder.HasMany(m => m.Payments).WithOne(p => p.Order).HasForeignKey(m => m.ReferenceNumber);


        builder.ToTable("tblOrders");
    }
```

PaymentConfiguration.cs:

```
    public void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<Payment> modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasKey(m => m.Id);

        modelBuilder.Property(m => m.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
        ... several other mappings...

        modelBuilder.HasOne(m => m.Order).WithMany(o => o.Payments).HasForeignKey(m => m.ReferenceNumber);

        modelBuilder.ToTable("tblPayments");
    }
```

when I debug the application, i obtain the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The relationship from 'Payment.Order' to 'Order.Payments' with foreign key properties {'ReferenceNumber' : string} cannot target the primary key {'Id' : int} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.'

This sounds pretty reasonable, but how can i set the relationship properly considering the situation mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have it both ways. It seems you're using an existing database, which literally does not have a foreign key. You can't simply tell EF to pretend as if there is one. You either need to alter that database so it has an appropriate foreign key or you need to dispense with the EF modeling of the relationship and just manually query the related entities. For example, to get the payments for a particular order:

```
var payments = db.Payments.Where(m => m.ReferenceNumber == order.ReferenceNumber);
```

Instead of the easier `order.Payments`, which requires the foreign key.

Comment: yeah, i'm using an existing database. i have to sort out if there's a possibility to add a foreign key to tblPayments, but i'm pessimistic due to the complexity of the applications that are already relying on this database

Comment: As long as there is always a one-to-one correlation between the reference number on both tables, adding a foreign key should have no impact on any application built before it was there. The issue would be if it's set as null, set to something that doesn't exist in the referenced table, or the principal side (probably orders) are ever deleted without also deleting related payments.